# Custom Class ToString() Override not showing up in WPF ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a WPF application built with MVVM and am trying to display a custom class in a combobox.  I am still getting the Namespace.Asset despite overriding the ToString Method to something easier on the eyes.  What am I doing wrong?
XAML code

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Drivers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDriver}" Grid.Row="20" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

ViewModel Code

```
    public List<Driver> Drivers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.drivers;
        }
        set
        {
            this.drivers = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Drivers");
        }
    }

    public Driver SelectedDriver
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedDriver;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedDriver = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDriver");
        }
    }
```

One of the custom classes code with overriden ToString

```
public class ExperimentalDriver : Driver
{
    public override DriverResponse GetDriverResponse(double time)
    {
         ... random unrelated code....
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Experimental Driver";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your reference is bad.  Remove the reference to the assembly with the ExperimentalDriver class and re-add it *as a project reference*.

Comment: It was a project reference, but I deleted it and re-added it for giggles and it is still showing up as a Namespace.Asset instead of "Experimental Driver"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to set the ToString() on the base class

Something like:

```
public class Driver
{
    protected string displayName;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return displayName;
    }
}
```

Then your class constructors for your sub classes would simply set the displayName

```
public class ExperimentalDriver : Driver
{
    public ExperimentalDriver()
    {
        displayName = "Experimental Driver";
    }
}
```

Comment: This works exactly as advertised, and it's slightly more elegant than my original solution.  I just discovered before you posted that what was causing the problem was the fact that I had public new abstract string ToString(); in my base class.  When I commented that out the problem disappeared as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.  I have an abstract class "Driver" in that abstract class I added the following code to require all my derived classes to have a ToString() method

```
public new abstract string ToString();
```

When I remove it the problem goes away.